# Me.Filter Access Code Syntax

Tags: email, ms-access, vba

I am trying to filter a form that emails only the current record. I have tried to do the me.filter command but cannot seem to get the syntax correct. I have provided the code below. The Current Date field is a date field and the Discover, Tail, and FleetID fields are text fields. I was told to put in the me.filter code the primary keys of the table that the form is linked to so the pdf that is produced does not print all the records linked to the form. Please let me know if you see something with my code. Thanks in advance :)

```
On Error GoTo errhandle
Me.Filter = "CurrentDate= #" & Me!CurrentDate & "#" And "Discover= '" & Me!Discover & "'" And "Tail= '" & Me!Tail & "'" And "FleetID= '" & Me!FleetID & "'" 
Me.FilterOn = True
DoCmd.SendObject acSendForm, "frmETIC", acFormatPDF, "email address", "", "", "Recovery Report", "Attached is the submitted Recovery Report"
exitErr:
Exit Sub
errhandle:
If Err.Number <> 2501 Then
MsgBox ("Email cancelled!")
End If
Resume exitEr
```

Comment: @Jens: "code broke, please help" is explicitly off topic at Code Review. Take a moment to review what kind of questions can be asked there: codereview.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: @Jens Im not getting like a specific error code but my error handle is activating so every time I hit the command button to send the email its just popping up "Email cancelled" like my message box says.

Comment: @Jens just kidding I removed my error handle code and Im getting a type mismatch error 13

Comment: @JeroenVannevel Seems I was blatantly mistaking about the purpose of that site. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All those And-operators are meant to be for the filtering, so they need to be inside the filter-string. Otherwise they are used as boolean operators in VBA, which will cause a type mismatch error when used on strings.

Another issues with your code is the date in the filter string. You will not get the desired result unless the date is formatted properly for use in a SQL criteria.

Replace the line Me.Filter = ... with the following to fix both problems.

```
Me.Filter = "CurrentDate= #" & Format(Me!CurrentDate, "yyyy\-mm\-dd") & "# AND Discover= '" & Me!Discover & "' AND Tail= '" & Me!Tail & "' AND FleetID= '" & Me!FleetID & "'"
```

If this filter string does not return the expected results, put a `Debug.Print Me.Filter` on the next line. This will print the actual filter string into the Immediate Window and allow you to see if it contains the expected values. For further debugging create a new Query in Access, switch to SQL View and enter `SELECT * FROM yourTable WHERE filterStringOutput` as SQL. Run the query. If it does not return the expected records, remove the criteria one by one to find the one that is causing problems.

Comment: YAY!! You rock :) thank you so much! One more thing though, my filter works now but when the email PDF pops up now its blank. Do you know why this would be?

Comment: I don't see any problem with your code there. What exactly do you mean by "blank"? Is it totally blank or is there just the data missing?

Comment: It shows the title of the form but no data is showing up. I will post a picture

Comment: This still might be an issue with the filter. Does the form show the expected record, or any record at all, before sending the PDF?

Comment: It shows the information the person enters into the form.. if that makes sense. The form is a submission for that when the button is clicked it submits the new record to the table connected to the form. I wanted the button to also send a copy of what the user had just entered into the form into an email that can be sent to a manager. I was told the me.filter command would do this but honestly Im not sure.

Comment: It did it before I had the filter it just showed the same record 20 times, the same amount of records that are in the table.

Comment: Your code should do exactly that. Most likely the issue now is the filter command not finding any record. You do enter data in all the fields used in the filter? And the CurrentDate is just the date without time?

Comment: Yes every field thats in the code must be entered, and yes the date is just the date without the time. Im wondering if it could be how I have the date formatted in the table. I have it under medium date is that correct? Also I am entering in the form itself the date in the format of 2015-04-20.

Comment: If the data type of CurrentDate in your table is "Date/Time" the format will not make any difference, as it just for the visual display of the content and not the actual data stored. - I just added some additional information for debugging issues with the filter to my answer.

Comment: I think I found the issue the FleetID value is in a combo box and when I look in the immediate windwon after I run the code the FleetID value keeps coming up blank. Do I need to add something to the code for combo box values?

Comment: No, usually do not need to add anything to deal with comboboxes. The code will work with comboboxes as well. 

Take a look at the properties of the combobox.  The "Bound Column" property defines which of the columns contains the data that will be used in the filter string as well as the data stored in the table. If this is empty, then take a look at the "Row Source", "Column Count" and "Column Widths" -properties. Maybe something is mixed up there.
 
If this does not help, I suggest you ask a new question, as that problem is not tied to filter-issue dealt with here.